# POD: How to insert tabs?

Tags: perl, perl-pod

How could I insert two tabs before each `Description` so that the tabs are shown in the `html`-output?

```
=pod

=head2 Head 2

My list:

=over

=item 

First Description A

=item 

Second Description B

=item 

Third Description C

=back

=cut
```

Comment: I don't think you can. Wouldn't it be better to do it using CSS since this is a matter of style rather than content?

Comment: That would mean adding `padding-left` to the corresponding elements via CSS. If you want it to be tabs, you could try a value of `8em` for each tab. That would require the `font-size` and `font-family` of the element to be the one of the code, though, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean how to make a definition list?

Try:

```
=over

=item First

Description A

=item Second

Description B

=item Third

Description C

=back
```

That will format a definition list with "First", "Second", and "Third" as the terms and "Description A", "Description B", and "Description C" as your descriptions.

If you need to change the formatting of a definition list on search.cpan.org or metacpan.org, you cannot. POD is a semantic documentation language and doesn't give the module author very much control over the layout and typography. The web site owner is the one that has the power to adjust the typography and such via CSS.

Comment: I would like all in one row, but for example between `First` and `Description A` tow tabs.

Comment: As the commenters above mention, POD does not do formatting. If you want to format something you must use CSS or something else. If you want it to look that way on metacpan.org or search.cpan.org you are out of luck. About the only way to control that there is to do it using a code block using PRE formatting.

Comment: Btw, if you define your definition list as shown here, the CSS is pretty easy to do side-by-side formatting, but this is no longer a Perl question. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/zostay/a4Jwd/

Comment: Could you add to your answer, that it is not possible.